Memory usage section on Safari when debugging iPhone on laptop is empty, how to populate?
I am trying to debug why my website is crashing on mobile (iPhone 13, iOS 17 something), so plugged in my phone to my MacBook laptop and opened Safari. I visit the page on my phone and can see the elements HTML of the page in my laptop Safari. So I went to the timelines tab and clicked the pencil icon to enable the "memory" section.
However, when I recorded a session, the memory section wasn't populated with anything. Why not. How do I get it to populate? I am thinking this issue is a memory leak or some other memory overload issue, so want to see better what's going on. How can I do that?
Notice in this image the memory section is blank.

